# How to convert SVG file to an image file in unity?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, svg

I imported SVG file into unity project and I need to create image files (PNG or JPEG) using that SVG file for further implementation. How can I do this using unity?

Comment: A SVG is XML format(text that you can open with Notepad).  The images are usually URL s and not actual images.  You can parse the XML to get the URL locations.

Comment: Maybe the [Vector Graphics Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0/manual/index.html) would help? It not only allows to create and edit SVGs at runtime but also has an [Importer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0/manual/index.html#svg-importer) to import existing SVG assets to 2D images

Comment: Thank you both for answers but here is actually what I want. I already imported SVG to the project and colored areas that I wanted using vector graphic package. Now I want to convert those colored svg into png or jpeg and do the further implementation. Do you know any method to do this ?

Comment: Again, Vector Graphics Package has all the answers needed - it can converts to Texture that Unity stores as pixel graphics instead of vector graphics depending on the settings